# Creating a Java based web service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis

I have a very basic Java based web service requirement.  Requirement is very simple, pass some String parameters, save them to database and generate a response ("success", "failed").  There is also a case where I need to return simple XML representation (SOAP message) of a simple Object:

```
<person>
 <name>the name</name>
 <address>the name</address>
......
</person>
```

Our current environment is Windows, Apache Tomcat 5, SQL Server.
I'm new to web services so I'm trying to figure out what technologies I could use to make this work.  For example:

1. Do I really need Apache Axis 2 to implement this or would it be overkill?
2. I saw a tutorial online where all that was needed to create web service was Eclipse, Lomboz plugin for Eclipse and Apache Tomcat.  Will I still need Apache Axis2 if I take this route?
3. Is it possible for Tomcat to process web service requests messages or do I need third party libraries?

I guess I'm looking for the easiest way to implement this.  Thank you.

Comment: As others have mentioned, web service need not mean either SOAP or even XML. But even if you do want to produce/consume XML, SOAP is not necessary; using JAXB for XML-to/from-Objects, and Servlet/JAX-RS (Jersey) as container it is very easy to do Plain Old Xml based web services. And also JSON-based ones.

Comment: Yes now I'm beginning to understand now.  We have Internet Web Services, which send XML over HTTP. We also have XML Web Services which will send XML SOAP messages.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need SOAP support? If you do, Axis is probably your best bet. Otherwise, I'd take a look at [Jersey.](http://jersey.java.net/)

Answer (score 2):

If it will be as simple as you have mentioned, why don't you look at [**RESTful**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html) Web Services? You can specify your resource calls through a GET, POST, DELETE or PUT HTTP methods.

There's a [blog tutorial](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/implementing_restful_web_services_in) on how to achieve this. It also shows you how you can return JSON strings/XML (depending on what you want).

Comment: Yeah this one looks like a good solution for me.  I also believe it has support for SOAP messages?  If yes then why would we need Apache Axis2?

Comment: Java 6 now have tools to facilitate developers in creating JAX-WS client/WSDL. You can create custom XML messages in RESTful applications. That all depends on your specification.

Answer (score 1):

A web framework would make this much easier (and actually maintainable), but you could just write a raw servlet to handle requests. You'll want to use an [XML object serialization method](http://jaxb.java.net/), though, or at the very least an [xml parsing library](http://www.xom.nu).

Comment: Alternatively, JSON is also a good format for interchanging data; others already mentioned JAX-RS (Jersey, RESTeasy, Wink) which works well with both XML and JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need axis for this one. But I'll advice you to look at Apache CXF, if in future you will need more support with web service apps. CXF just like axis2 is an implimentation of jax-ws but with an advantage of supporting jax-rs (rest). This means you can expose both REST and SOAP web service interfaces.